# How to print const variable type inside html code

Tags: javascript, html

My code looks like this

```
{% load static %}
{% block extrascript %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/batch/batch_detail.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/audit_log/audit_log.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
        const CURRENCY = currency_symbol('{{ currency }}');
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Somewhere down in the HTML code, I want to print the CURRECY js variable.

```
<br>
<b><label>Amount: </label></b>
    {{CURRENCY}}{{ source_amount.INCORRECT_FEE | default:0 }}
<br>
```

But not able to print it.
Any pointers or idea?

Comment: tell us what template system are you using

Comment: because CURRENCY variable is declared in a window object you can access its value like this window.CURRENCY. In your case you should know how to print javascript code in your template system

Comment: I am not sure about it, can you give me some pointers? 
I am using html and javascript for the first time in my life. Have been a backend server developer.

Comment: I understand, I mean this code {% block extrascript %} for example looks to my like twig template system, I ask you about what systems you use because in the documentation there may have been described a way to print values in javascript variables. Tell us what framewrok you use, so we could guess what template system you are using and so search from there

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/common.css' %}">{# TODO: Fix stylesheets and move to bottom #}
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'semantic-ui/semantic.css' %}"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery.datetimepicker.css' %}"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/dataTables.semanticui.min.css' %}"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/Chart.css' %}" />

Comment: <script src="{% static 'js/underscore-min.js' %}"></script>
 <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
 <script src="{% static 'semantic-ui/semantic.js' %}"></script>
 <script src="{% static 'js/moment.min.js' %}"></script>
 <script src="{% static 'js/moment-timezone-with-data.js' %}"></script>
 <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.datetimepicker.js' %}"></script>
 <script src="{% static 'js/common.js' %}"></script>
 <script src="{% static 'js/menu.js' %}"></script>

Comment: <script src="{% static 'js/kitchen_sink/kitchen_sink.js' %}"></script>
 <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.dataTables.min.js' %}"></script>
 <script src="{% static 'js/dataTables.semanticui.min.js' %}"></script>
 <script src="{% static 'js/Chart.js' %}"></script>
 <script src="{% static 'js/utils.js' %}"></script>
 <script src="{% static 'js/acl.js' %}"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use JS variable in html directly in plain html+javascript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>This example writes "Hello JavaScript versio" into an HTML element with id="demo":</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var version = 5;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript version" + version;
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

The above code is an example of using variable values in HTML.